# SQL statement to return the current step in a list of steps that should be passed through and whether the process has ended or not

Tags: mysql, sql

```
 Name  | Position | Approved
----------------------------
Step 1 |    1     |    1
Step 2 |    2     |    0
Step 3 |    3     |   -1
Step 4 |    4     |   -1
```

I have a database table with the above data. It stores the various steps associated with a request. The steps are ordered by the `position` column. Thus I'm able to know which step comes after which.

Is it possible to have an SQL statement that returns the current step and whether the request has been ended or not

**Algorithm for Current Step**

1. Select all steps ordered by position in ascending order.
2. If step has approved to be `0`, return current step
3. If step has approved to be `1` and is last step, return current step
4. If step has approved to be `-1`, and is (first step or the previous has approved to be `1`), return current step

**Algorithm for Request ended**

1. If current step has -1, request has **not** ended
2. If current step has 0 or 1, request has ended

For the above table, Current step is `Stage 2` and request has ended.

Can this be achieved using SQL? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: The current step will always be 4 - unless you mean 'the lowest step having approved = -1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d33f7/2) identifies the current step  and also whether the request has ended or not. However , since I was not able to identify the latest request, I have omitted the last 2 conditions from the 2nd algorithm.

```
 select *
,case when t1.approved=0 then 'ended'
      when t1.approved=-1 then 'not ended'
      end as stat
from (select Name, Position, Approved from table1 t2
where 
(case when approved=0 then 1
      when position =(select max(position) from table1) and approved=1 then 1  
      when (position= 1 and approved=-1) or (approved=-1 and 1=(select approved from table1 t1 where t1.position=t2.position-1))then 1 
else 0
end) =1 
      order by position)t1
limit 1
```

Comment: Hey @Kiril, given my algorigthm, having `("Step 1", 1, 1),
 ("Step 2", 2, 1),
 ("Step 3", 3, 1),
 ("Step 4", 4, -1)` is supposed to return Step 3 only

Comment: Updated.However, according to your requirements it should return Step 4, -1

Comment: thanks @Kiril. I can now update to fit into my exact scenario. I couldn't think of a way to implement from SQL so I already implemented in my php script. However, which would you consider more efficient. From SQL or from code.

Comment: The above query returns only one row from your table, while if you are coding it in PHP by quering the entire table and filtering the results, the overhead will be larger.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE grief
(Name  VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,Position INT NOT NULL
,Approved INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO grief VALUES
('denial',1,1),
('anger',2,0),
('bargaining',3,-1),
('depression',4,-1),
('acceptance',5,-1)

SELECT x.* 
  FROM grief x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT MAX(position) max_position 
         FROM grief 
        WHERE approved <> -1 
     ) y 
    ON y.max_position = x.position;

+-------+----------+----------+
| Name  | Position | Approved |
+-------+----------+----------+
| anger |        2 |        0 |
+-------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: `anger` is supposed to be the result given my algorithm @Strawberry

Comment: Please see edit. But this solution wilfully ignores the possibility that 0 might be followed by a 1 - because that's just weird!